# Do workflows in PWA kick off when you save project?

Tags: project-server, project-online, pwa

Are workflows supposed to kick off whenever you edit then save information in PWA?  All my projects seem (from Logging) only to ever get workflows run when you create the project or manually "Change or Restart Workflow."   I would expect that the workflows would run whenever a change to PWA occurs, and that the workflow would start in the same stage that it was in when the edits started.   Is that the behavior?  Why is it not kicking off on a save?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I've not seen the type of behavior that you are describing, which is more typical of a standard SharePoint workflow. Project Server workflows are basically manual workflows that you push forward to the next stage as you see fit. A typical scenario is a project lifecycle. Moving to the next stage is a deliberate action that you take when needed.

Let me know if this makes sense or if I misunderstood your question. For anyone else, please let me know if I'm mistaken on this, as it would improve my feelings towards PWA.